# PHP math converting amounts

Tags: php, math, floor

I am trying to convert cricket overs i.e `6` to show `0.6` and `12` to show `1.6`. I got it all working except for the last part where it returns the full figure.

My code:

```
foreach($numberofballs as $x){
    $first = floor($x / 6);
    $last = $x - ($first * 6);
    echo $first.'.'.$last;
}
```

Lets assign an array for testing suppose the below array needs to be converted for this loop

```
$numberofballs = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

foreach($numberofballs as $x){
    $first = floor($x / 6);
    $last = $x - ($first * 6);
    echo $first.'.'.$last;
}

/* notes
for 1 it does it right = 0.1
for 2 it does it right = 0.2
for 3 it does it right = 0.3
for 4 it does it right = 0.4
for 5 it does it right = 0.5
how its supposed to work for 6:
for 6 I do not want to get = 1 I would like to get 0.6 and no there is never 0.7
/ end notes */
```

I am not saying the above code is wrong, I am just wishing to get the end value correct.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the [base_convert function](http://www.php.net/base_convert)? Like so: base_convert($points/10, 10, 6) or a simple modulus-operation: $result = ($points%6)/10;

Comment: it does not give you the correct output at all tried few methods already the above solution works best for this purpose however the end result is not as desired.

Comment: @Tularis - your approaches don't adjust for the notation using x.6 as the 10 instead of rolling over to x.0. I've tweaked your idea as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach( $numberofballs as $x){


       $first = floor($x / 6);
       $last = $x - ($first * 6);
       if($last==0 && $first>0) {$last=6; $first-=1;}
       echo $first.'.'.$last;
    }
```

Comment: if($last==0), and will be ok. :)

Comment: The above Solution works just as desired.
@DhruvJoshi Thank you!, We make it all beautiful! and nevermind you too!

Comment: @Genus Glad to be of use!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting way to handle the problem using `base_convert` but still handling `.6` as the tenth place instead of rolling over after .5:

```
$numberofballs = range(1,24);

foreach( $numberofballs as $x){

    $round = ceil($x/6) - 1;
    echo  base_convert($x + $round, 10, 7)/10;

}
```

By using base 7, you retain the .6, but obviously it will be off by 1 for the second group and 2 for the third group, etc.  But if we take calculate the round based on the current ball (with the first round being 0, the second 1, etc) and add that to the current ball count before the base convert, it will always be adjusted correctly and still .1 through .6 as the notation.

This avoids the need for a conditional for the adjustment on the 6, 12, 18, etc. as the round calculation adjusts for it regardless of which ball is being calculated. It also can be converted to a simple function to convert any number to the correct notation without needing to track the previous number:

```
function bowls2overs($ball_number) {

    $round = ceil($ball_number/6) - 1;
    return base_convert($ball_number + $round, 10, 7)/10;

}
```

Comment: your method might work too but i haven't tried it yet. its looks to be working from the look of it. thanks.